# How do I force the window to draw in Win32?

Tags: winapi, draw

My window in invalidated as part of a certain function called by a message processed by WndProc().  However I need the contents of the window to redrawn right then, before my function continues.  Is there a way to call WndProc(hWnd, WM_CREATE, NULL, NULL) or something similar from my external function?

Comment: [`UpdateWindow(hwnd);`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145167(v=vs.85).aspx), unless they changed something in the last 20 years. Are you certain the region you need to repaint is actually marked *invalid*? if not, see [InvalidateRect()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145002(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: YOU ARE MY FAVORITE OF ALL THE PEOPLE.  I can finally go to sleep now.

Comment: ....but I probably won't